# How to find the center of the palm of hand

Tags: c++, opencv

**Hi guys iam new to here.i was able to detect hand and the finger tips using opencv..  but iam really stuck in getting center of the palm of hand..Need guidance.. Thanx in advance.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? What algorithm have you used to detect the hand and the finger tips?

Comment: i read this tutorial http://blog.candescent.ch/2011/04/center-of-palm-hand-tracking.html  but i dnt undrstnd the it clearly...i think i dnt have proper understand abt convexity defect function stores defects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for the gap between middle finger and ring finger. Than, assuming you know the inclination of the hand (if not you should look for a method to determine it, for example tracing a line from the between index finger and medium finger to the gap between middle finger and little finger), you could trace a line perpendicular to the hand's inclination. Then you look for the gap between thumb and index and you trace a line parallel to hand's inclination. The intersection between this two lines is reasonably near to the center of the hand.

Comment: btw i have got the middle finger by getting the topmost point..but it changes when i rotate my hand..so how can i apply your algorithm here?

Comment: the middle finger isn't always the topmost point. I think you should apply Viola-Jones to find the hand. Then, you should apply again Viola-Jones to identify the points where two fingers join the hand. And then you can apply this algoritm